# Is auto-scrapping by the workbench a good idea?

Tags: fallout-4

You can scrap junk automatically if you put it into the workbench and start building things. However, there is this perk called "Scrapper" with 2 levels. Will this apply on auto-scrap feature from the work bench too, or do I need to manually scrap all materials?

Answer (score 7):

No. The "Scrapper" perk applies to weapons and armor, which can not be auto-scrapped in this way.